# Could not find a package configuration file provided by "absl" with any of the following names: abslConfig.cmake absl-config.cmake

Tags: c++, ubuntu, cmake, abseil

Trying to run the Google cpu checker:

https://github.com/google/cpu-check

I get the following error when running `cmake ..` in the "Building" section:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:86 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findabsl.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "absl", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "absl" with any of
  the following names:

    abslConfig.cmake
    absl-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "absl" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "absl_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "absl"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Comment: Try to run `cmake -D CMAKE_FIND_DEBUG_MODE=ON ..` ; it should show you the system paths where CMake is looking for your library. Then you can easily verify if the ABSL cmake file is there or not.

Comment: So, do you have Abseil-cpp installed? This requirement is noted in the [prerequisites](https://github.com/google/cpu-check#prerequisites) for the project you want to build.

Comment: @Tsyvarev yes the Abseil-cpp is installed I was using this link for the installation instructions https://abseil.io/docs/cpp/quickstart#prerequisites

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and I could resolve it with adding the flag `-DBUILD_DEPS=ON` to the end of my `cmake` command.